# Weird routing error in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been converting my Rails 2.3.9 application to Rails 3.0 and everything has been going well. I've created a lot of routes with the new system so I feel like I know how to do this. However, I recently got a routing error I can't solve.

I have a users resource defined like this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'activate'
    get 'edit_password'
    post 'update_password'
  end

  collection do
    get 'forgot_password'
    post 'send_reset_instructions'
  end
end
```

The failing route is update_password. If I change it to a get method it works. But not when used as a post, with data coming from a form in "edit_password".

This is the error message:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/users/31/update_password"
```

This is the (relevant) output of *rake routes*:

```
                activate_user GET    /users/:id/activate(.:format)                               {:action=>"activate", :controller=>"users"}
           edit_password_user GET    /users/:id/edit_password(.:format)                          {:action=>"edit_password", :controller=>"users"}
         update_password_user POST   /users/:id/update_password(.:format)                        {:action=>"update_password", :controller=>"users"}
        forgot_password_users GET    /users/forgot_password(.:format)                            {:action=>"forgot_password", :controller=>"users"}
send_reset_instructions_users POST   /users/send_reset_instructions(.:format)                    {:action=>"send_reset_instructions", :controller=>"users"}
                        users GET    /users(.:format)                                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                        users POST   /users(.:format)                                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
                    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                         user PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                         user DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

Finally, this is the output of the web server for that request (webrick):

```
Started POST "/users/31/update_password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-10-14 23:30:59 +0200
  SQL (1.5ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
  SQL (0.7ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'


ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/31/update_password"):


Rendered /home/jonatan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Can you find any logic in this?

I'm using the latest Rails available through gem (3.0.1). At first I did override *to_param* in the User-model to use the username, but the problem is the same no matter what.

I've checked for misspellings in the update_password method of the model, and also made sure it is not private.

Comment: What happens if you change it from update_password to foo (and your controller method as well as the view name)?

Comment: I've tried to change it to "updatera_password" (almost swedish ;)) but that didn't help either. I thought maybe update_password was som keyword of some kind, but that wasn't the case obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed this as well, only with the POST method and only when using "member", so same as your example, ie:

```
resources :forum_posts do
  member do
    post :preview
  end
end
```

will trigger this, but changing it to GET or using collection both work fine, so seems to be a bug with rails routes; I get around this for now by adding the following just above my resources :forum_posts do line:

```
match '/forum_posts/:id/preview(.:format)', :to => "forum_posts#preview", :as => :preview_forum_post
```

then everything continues working; easy temporary fix.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Your workaround works. Strange that bugs like this, that should be easy to find, can slip through ...