# Active Record Reputation System Rails 4 fork find_with_reputation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app with Users and Fonts. I set up ARRSystem and USers can Like, Like can be seen on the Font show page. However, when I try to order them by Likes with

```
def index
    @fonts = Font.find_with_reputation(:likes, :all, {:order => 'likes desc'})
end
```

It doesn't work. No sorting happens. I would like to have "Most Popular" and "Most Recent" in my navigation menu, but can't get this to work. I am using this exact gemfile: https://github.com/NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system/tree/rails4

Comment: it's not possible to help you without providing any logs or something like that. go here and read about how to debug a rails application http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: It should work according to tests. I can't dig into this right now, but what's generated query?

Comment: Rails Server tells me this when loading Index page: Rendered /Users/USername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout

Comment: Its got something to do with the way I'm routing- I'm routing like Ryan does in the Railscast, which is:

    resources :fonts do 
        member { get :like }
    end

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937823/weird-routing-error-in-rails-3-0

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around, I have images which I am trying to sort desc based upon upvotes:

My Solution:

In images_controller.rb (index method)

```
image_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT target_id FROM rs_reputations     WHERE target_type = 'Image' ORDER BY value DESC")
image_ids = image_ids.map { |item| item = item[0] }
@images = []
image_ids.each { |id| @images << Image.find(id) }
```

I was looking at my server logs and it looks like the instead of pulling all images with one query, descending, 'find_with_reputation' queries for each item (and therefore cannot sort). It also doesnt query 'value'.

```
ReputationSystem::Reputation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "rs_reputations".* FROM "rs_reputations" WHERE "rs_reputations"."reputation_name" = 'votes' AND "rs_reputations"."target_id" = 14 AND "rs_reputations"."target_type" = 'Image' LIMIT 1
ReputationSystem::Reputation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rs_reputations".* FROM "rs_reputations" WHERE "rs_reputations"."reputation_name" = 'votes' AND "rs_reputations"."target_id" = 15 AND "rs_reputations"."target_type" = 'Image' LIMIT 1
ReputationSystem::Reputation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rs_reputations".* FROM "rs_reputations" WHERE "rs_reputations"."reputation_name" = 'votes' AND "rs_reputations"."target_id" = 17 AND "rs_reputations"."target_type" = 'Image' LIMIT 1
```

Solution:
Either condense the Query into one, or push each query result into an array and then sort by value.

EDIT:  This works fine in development with MySQL but not so much in PostgreSQL.  I receive a PG::RESULT object which I do not quite know how to handle.